# Torsion in a tensor product over a group ring

Tags: gr.group-theory, tensor-products, profinite-groups, noncommutative-rings, group-algebras

Let $\Gamma$ be a finitely generated dense subgroup of a pro-$p$ group $G$. Let $\mathbb Z_p$ be the ring of $p$-adic numbers. Denote by $\mathbb Z_p[[G]]$ the completed group algebra.

> Is it true that the tensor product $\mathbb Z_p[[G]]\otimes_{\mathbb Z_p[\Gamma]} \mathbb Z_p[[G]]$ is torsion-free as an abelian group?

Comment: The completed group algebra is by definition the projective limit of $\mathbf{Z}_p[G/U]$ where $U$ ranges over [open] finite index subgroups, is that correct?

Comment: @Ycor yes, that's true.

Comment: A trivial remark is that the question is equivalent to asking whether it has a no element of order $p$ (since this is a $\mathbf{Z}_p$-module).